# Explicit Countable Orthonormal Basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, orthonormal, separable-spaces

I was working with my thesis and I needed to use the existence of a countable orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R}).$

It should be true that the Hilbert Space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is separable, this because the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\lambda),$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, is $\sigma-$finite.

Now, this implies that there exists a countable orthonormal basis, but this comes from an abstract type of reasoning, i.e. the Zorn's Lemma for the existence of an orthonormal basis and the use of separability to say that it is countable.

> The question that came up to me is: is there an explicit representation of this basis?

The answer should be no, otherwise the use of the continuous Fourier transform doesn't make much sense, but who knows, perhaps there are some good reasons to prefer the continuous transform even if there is a countable basis.

My idea was to take inspiration from the system $\{sin(\frac{n x}{m})\}_{n,m\in\mathbb{N}},$ but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I recommend you the set $\{e^{nx}\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$-. At least, it is the basis we use in Quantum mechanics.

Comment: It is just that $x\mapsto e^{nx}$ is not an $L^2(\mathbb {R})$ function. Maybe you can consider the Haar wavelet system. It is quite a simple construction and does the job, i.e., forms an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: The Hermite functions are a countable orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions

Comment: Thanks to everybody! It is curious that the question came from a point in my thesis about Hermite Polynomials and that the answer uses the same ones :) 
Do you have an idea about why such a basis is not used nor presented in basic Fourier analysis?

Comment: I'm sorry  I wanted to say $\{e^{inx}\}$. This is actually the set used in Quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in the comments, the Hermite functions will work. You can think of them as being obtained by applying Gram-Schmidt to the functions $x^n e^{- \frac{x^2}{2} }$ (up to some factors of $2$ depending on your conventions).

The point of the Fourier basis of $L^2(S^1)$ is not just that it's a countable orthonormal basis, it's also that it diagonalizes translation, or said another way, that it diagonalizes differentiation; this is why it's useful for solving differential equations, which were the original motivation for Fourier series (Fourier used them to solve the heat equation). The Hermite basis is great but it doesn't do this.

Comment: The Hermite functions diagonalize the Fourier transform, which diagonalizes differentiation.:-)

Comment: Ok so the point is that the countability is ok, but you often need some diagonal properties! Thanks :)

Comment: In addition to @DisintegratingByParts' point about Fourier transform, it is also worth appreciating that the Hermite functions (with exponential factor) are exactly the $L^2$ eigenfunctions for $={d^2\over dx^2}+x^2$, are obtained by starting with the "lowest" one, and "raising" by ${d\over dx}-x$...  in the "ladder" relations. Indeed, this operator has compact resolvent (because the "potential" $x^2$ acts as a "confining potential"). Many amusing features.

Answer (score 2):

I know there's already an accepted answer, but my favorite is the brute force basis taking the set of exponentials $e^{2\pi i k(x-n)}$, each with $x$ restricted to [$n,n+1$) $\forall k,n\in \mathbb{N}$, which is countable by the same Cantor ordering of $(k,n)$ as for the rationals $k/n$. More pedantically, I guess the basis is $e^{2\pi i k(x-n)}\cdot I_{n,n+1}(x)$, where $I_{a,b}(x)$ is an indicator function for that interval.

Comment: Does it work at all? :)

Comment: It's certainly a valid basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ in bijection with the typical Fourier basis on a finite interval.